# CSS3 selector selecting parent based on firstchild

Tags: jquery-selectors, css, css-selectors

Is there some CSS3 selector that I can write to do the following:

Select the "LI" whose first child is an "A"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, unfortunately not, because you'd be selecting an ancestor based on its descendant. This operates against the 'cascade' of the Cascading Style Sheets, sadly. Though it's a feature that I would much appreciate were it ever to be possible.

Though given the tag 'jquery-selectors' you could, in jQuery, use:

```
$('li:has("> a:first-child")')...
```

[Verified with a JS Fiddle demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/zTwvB/1/).

CSS 3 briefly had a [`:contains() pseudo-selector`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#content-selectors) that *might* have been useful for this, but since appears to have been removed.

---

**Edited** to incorporate @patrick dw's correction (from `$('li:has("> a")')...` to the above example.
**Edited** to update the demo URL to a demonstration of the corrected jQuery selector.

Comment: Almost. You'll need the `:first-child` selector as well. `$('li:has("> a:first-child")')`

Comment: @patrick dw: I considered that when I put it together and then thought *no, the `>` implies first-child...* Yes, I *am* an idiot... =) And thank you for the catch and correction, it's appreciated.

Comment: It's very odd receiving an up-vote on a comment in which I lay claim to be 'an idiot.' Even if said claim is entirely accurate... =S

Comment: I haven't used selectors like that before. Very nice, thanks. :)

Comment: @Aishwar, I should, really, have linked to the [jQuery API for the `:has()` pseudo-selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/), but I forgot. See above comment... =b Also, you're welcome, I'm glad to have been of help =)

Comment: @David: Sorry, that was just my "you're welcome". I wasn't focused on the *"idiot"* part. I probably should have clarified. ;o)

Comment: @patrick, that was my assumption, to be honest; but then I realised what the other part of the comment was, and was quite amused by it =)